# Probabilités conditionnelles

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

In an industrial area, three production units are accused of pollution following the discharge into the open air without treatment in the river. The first unit manufactures copper products, the other two produce copper and lead products. It is estimated that the risks of pollution in second unit are twice less than in the other two units. If any pollution in the river is detected, which production unit will we tend to incriminate if the pollutant is (1) copper? (2) lead?

Comment: Je pense que la plupart des gens ici ne comprennent pas francais. Je récommende que vous écrivez cela en anglais.

Comment: Néanmoins bienvenue a StackExchange 

Comment: *Welcome to the site !* Being French myself, I think that we have two incredible ways to exchange : mathematics + English (even if not good which is probably my case). So, *faites un effort !*

Comment: Merci pour votre aide. Je vais le traduire en anglais.

Comment: Vue que vous êtes nouveau, lorsque vous trouvez qune réponse est utile et correcte vous pouvez l'approuver .pour donner du crédit a la personne qui vous a répondu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the pollution is made by lead .
We can eliminate the first unity . So we need to choose or 2,3 unity 2 is more sure so we need to incriminate 3
If the pollution is made by copper .
If we estimate that a unity that produced copper and lead is less likely that reject only copper. then we need to incriminate 1.

Comment: Here is a translation for the problem if that helps.

Comment: In an industrial area, three production units are accused of pollution following the discharge into the open air without treatment in the river. The first unit manufactures copper products, the other two produce copper and plumb products. It is estimated that the risks of pollution in second unit are twice less than in the other two units. If any pollution in the river is detected, which production unit will we tend to incriminate if the pollutant is (1) copper? (2) plumb?

Comment: The way i see it is that we have to estimate the risks for each unit and than compare between them.

Comment: A tree diagram seems to be the best way to resolve this problem for me  . We know that the risks in unit 2 are two times less than in the other units wich means that if we call the risks for unit 1 = A / unit 2 = B / unit 3 =C   then A=C=3B    and if we simplify  we sshould get that A=C=3/7 and B=1/7

Comment: However the risks calculated above are global aka they include both copper and plumb which means we have to have the percentages for these last two and then proceed with the tree diagramm in order to find our conditional risks.

Comment: Je pense que dans tout les cas l'exercice est mal défini car nous ne pouvons guère affirmé de façon certaine les probabilités .par exemple si nous pouvons déduire de la question que lorsque une unité produit du plomb et du cuivre alors il est moins probable que l'unité pollue seulement au cuivre alors là question est resoluble sinon la question n'est pas définie . Dans le cas où vous préférez écrire en français je vous conseille le site les-mathematiques

Comment: Merci pour votre aide. Le probleme ici peut etre resolue si on peut determiner les pourcentages du cuivre et du plomb , mais apparemment c'est presque impossible de les determiner donc j'ai penser qu'on doit discuter les resultats a base des ces deux derniers comme des inconnues peut etre mais je ne sais pas. je n'ai jamais vu un cas pareil de probabilités ou on discute les resultats comme ça.

Comment: Anonyme is onto something here. Certainly we can put
$$
P(\text{1 leaks Copper}) = p \qquad P(\text{1 leaks Lead}) = 0 
$$
but how about production units 2 and 3? Can we say, for example
$$
P(\text{2 leaks Copper}) = p/2 \qquad P(\text{2 leaks Lead}) = p/2
$$
or how? It's not really defined how the leaks of different kind relate to each other and to the general probability of a leak. Are the Copper leaks and Lead leaks independent?

Comment: @MattiP. actually i believe that this problem can be solved by a simple and intuitive application of bayes theorem however it appears to me that you're right and that some informations might be missing.